# Is there such design pattern? How to call it?

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions, wrapper, provider

I have such design:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public abstract List<Sth> getSth();
}

public class MyConcreteImplementation implements MyInterface {
    private ConcreteSth mSth = new ConcreteSth();

    public List<Sth> getSth(){
        return mSth.getSth(additionalParams); 
    }
}
```

Purpose of code above is to provide unified method to be called from other classes.

Can this be called a pattern? If so how to name it?

Comment: Who cares what it's called?  Why do you need a name for it?  You're just using an interface to create an API.

Comment: @Erick: you start caring about a name when you want your colleagues to use it.

Comment: @Erick: having common terminology with which to discuss code can be a fairly useful thing. Being able to use a precise name for something reduces any potential ambiguity caused by a more verbose description, and allows for a usable shorthand to develop.

Comment: If you always talk about your code in patterns, you will only be able to work with people who understand patterns.  If you just build good API's which make sense, any programmer can understand it.  Additionally, they will want to use it because it solves a problem.  I understand this approach requires a bit more personal responsibility.

Comment: @Erick: There is nothing wrong with the question. This has a lot to do with programming compared to some other questions in SO. Recognizing a design pattern in a application make it easy for the reader to understand how to properly maintain the application. Sorry... but I really don't agree with you.

Comment: I agree that there's nothing wrong with the question.  In fact, I upvoted it pretty much because of all this interesting discussion it has fostered.  I compare knowing design patterns to knowing openings in chess.  They're great for beginners wrapping their heads around how to start building something, or to understand different things that programming can do.  Once you gain experience, though, you pretty much just code whatever you need to get the job done, and don't worry so much about the pattern you're creating.

Comment: @Erick yes but there is nothing wrong with recognizing a pattern. It's a skill and should not be discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Adapter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

> Purpose of code above is to provide unified method to be called from other classes.

That's really sound like Adapter. You want to have a certain class adapted to your interface. The interface here is `MyInterface` and the adaptee is `ConcreteSth`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). It adapts `ConcreteSth` to `MyInterface`.

Anyway, if it does the work you expect from it, you should be asking about whether it's a pattern only out of curiousity.

Comment: I don't think it's required to be able to tell the Adapter which Adaptee it should use.

Comment: @bozho - What do you think about my answer? :)

Comment: @xtofl I think you should. Otherwise how would it know what to adapt to?

Comment: See the example in Java section of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern. It's not required to tell the adapter which adaptee it use.

Comment: in Java section. Code of LegacyLine, LegacyRectangle, Shape

Comment: @nanda @xtofl - although I don't like the example in wikipedia with instantiating the adaptee, I should agree it's a valid case for adapter. Updated the answer

Comment: @Bozho... well not to be such jerk, but I think the proper response is to close your answer, don't you think so? :)

Comment: @Bozho don't know but I think that should be the etiquette of duplicating answer that doesn't give more value. Maybe I'm wrong, though...

Comment: @nanda At the time I was writing my answer there was no other answer specifying that it is the adapter pattern. If there was, I wouldn't add mine. (yes, there is a 2 minute difference, but I was writing it at that time)

Comment: @Bozho your original answer is Adapter (almost...) while your modified is just Adapter. And by the time you modified your answer you know there is an exact answer as your modified answer. Anyway... if you decide to keep your answer, so be it.

Answer (score 3):

**You are just following basic object oriented design here**. This looks like simple [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) to me and if you are really keen on a design pattern I could stretch it to being a form of [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Comment: Then maybe we shouldn't have design pattern after all. They are all after all just combination of composition, relation, etc...

Comment: Design patterns are good for inexperienced programmers to learn what kinds of things can be done in object-oriented design.  It's something entirely different to retro-fit a pattern onto code that you've already created to solve a problem.

Comment: guys the key is here: "Purpose of code above is to provide unified method to be called from other classes." Sound really an adapter for me...

Comment: Before you start worrying about design patterns you really need to understand the very basics of Object Oriented Design :)

Comment: are you assuming OP and me don't understand basics of OOD?

Answer (score 0):

I would call it an Adapter: it wraps another method (`MyInterface.getSth`) around an existing interface (i.e. the `ConcreteSth`), without changing the functionality.

Answer (score -2):

Factory method?

The essence of the Factory method Pattern is to "Define an interface for creating an object, but let the subclasses decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: there's no creation in there.

Comment: This is not a factory pattern.